# Saving XML results into document or database

Tags: php, xml, ajax, xml-parsing

I have a form that sends the information to an api and gets a response in XML format.  I need to know what the best way to document/parse the results (text document, or anything else).  If possible i would like the responses to all save into one document and not single documents for every result.

i'm using an ajax post method and the localproxy code where the results code needs to be is below

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://integrate.com/api/test.ashx'); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents('mydata.xml', $result, FILE_APPEND);

die('<h1>Thanks!</h1>');

?>
```

the xml data comes in the format below

```
<result>
<success>0</success>
<leadid/>
<errors>
<error>Missing Field: </error>
</errors>
</result>
```

The file gets created and has content in it now, this is the content, it is an error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>

<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Content Length</h2>

<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. There is an invalid content length or chunk length in the request.</p>

</BODY></HTML>
```

what does this mean? the api server isn't accepted the request?

Comment: You are looking for a method to parse XML? There is a lot of basic documentation out there for that purpose. Useful Google queries include `php parse xml` which will give you an overview over the libraries available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for parsing xml, use [`XML parser`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php)

To save the result in a file, appending each result to the end of the file you could use [`file_put_contents($filename, $data, FILE_APPEND)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

e.g.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://integrate.com/api/test.ashx');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
file_put_contents('mydata.xml', $result, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

If you need to send a post request add:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'param=value&param=value'); // to be replace with valid query string
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

Comment: i keep getting an error log error "Filename cannot be empty" also will this save the file in the same directory as the localproxy.php or do i have to choose that?

Comment: @user1532944 Well, specify a filename to get rid of the error. Yes, it will save the file to the same directory.

Comment: got that, should it be saved as an .xml since thats the format it is being sent in?  It saved but contained 0 data, am i doing something else wrong?

    $result = file_put_contents('mydata.xml', $data, FILE_APPEND);

this is my code i have now

Comment: `$data` variable actually should contain *data to be saved*. In you case you can just replace `$data` with `$result`.

Comment: i edited my question to what i currently have in the localproxy.php and the file that gets saved has that response in it. do you know what the problem is now?

Comment: @user1532944 You are sending POST request, specifying $_POST array instead of query string. Either remove everything related to POST or provide valid query string. I'll edit my answer with an examples.